# I can't figure out how to delete a list from my list view and database

Tags: java, sql, listview, android-studio-2.3

This is my current failed attempt at deleting a list. The selected list seems to get deleted,but once the app is restarted the deleted list reappears in my list view. I've been struggling with this for about an hour now. I'm fairly new to Android Studio or android development in general

Here is my DataBaseHelper class

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context){super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);}
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "ITEM1 TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

public boolean addData(String item1){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item1);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result== -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;

    }
}

public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}



public DatabaseHelper(Context context){super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);}
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "ITEM1 TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

public boolean addData(String item1){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item1);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result== -1){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;

    }
}

public Cursor getListContents(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}

public boolean deleteRow(long RowId){
   return  db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL1 + "=" + RowId,null)>0;
}
```

}

My Main class

```
DatabaseHelper myDB;
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected  void onCreate( Bundle saveInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
    setContentView(listview_item);

    final ListView listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    final ArrayList<String> theList= new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
    final ArrayAdapter listAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);



    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
              myDB.deleteRow(id);
            theList.remove(position);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

    });


    if (data.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "Database was empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
        Collections.reverse(theList);
    }





    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewListContents.this, Note.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    // Take appropriate action for each action item click<br />
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_credits:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where are you doing the actual deleting?

Comment: I've added my Main class. Where the deleting is being done.

Comment: Are you expecting that `theList.remove(position);` will remove the item? I'm assuming that your list adapter fills `theList` with the contents of the rows in your database table. However once you get that list, note that it is only a representation of the rows in the database and not the actual rows themselves, so whatever changes you make to `theList` will not be reflected in the table. You' will have to ensure that your list Adapter (which is how I'm assuming you talk to the DB) runs the appropriate SQL statement to delete the row from the DB.

Comment: I realized that a while ago. but I'm now running into difficulties while creating a deleterow method in my databasehelper class. And i can't find a fix anywhere online. I'm a complete nood at this and need some help.

Comment: okay, what does your sql delete look like